# assigning values in loop to array of character pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I can't assign values to a char array in loop, doing it contains same value in every array value

for example this works

```
char* foo[3];

foo[0] = "mango"; foo[1] = "kiwi"; foo[2] = "banana";

int i=0; for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
{
   printf("%s\n",foo[i]); 
}
```

but this doesn't and I don't understand why.

```
char* foo[3]; int i=0;

for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
  char temp[5];
  sprintf(temp,"VAL:%d",i);
  foo[i] = temp; 
}

for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
{
  printf("%s\n",foo[i]); 
}
```

please help and thanks in advance

Comment: `for(i=0;i<3;i++) { char temp[5]; sprintf(temp,"VAL:%d",i); foo[i] = temp; }` assigns a pointer to a local variable that doesn't exist anymore after the loop body finished. Didn't your compiler warn about that?

Comment: i am using gcc with code::blocks, the log window was closed because i thought it won't take much time to remember some stuff , sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that in C, a `char*` does not actually store a string, but it stores the address of a memory location that will be treated as the first character of a string.

In your first example, each element of the `foo` array holds the address of a different string-literal.
In your second example, each element of the `foo` array is made to point to the local variable `temp`. Although each iteration through the loop results in a separate instance of `temp`, any sane compiler will place all those instances on top of each other, thus giving the results you experience.

The solution is either to use a 2D array:

```
char foo[3][6]; int i=0;

for (i=0; i<3; i++) { sprintf(foo[i],"VAL:%d", i); }

for (i=0; i<3; i++) { printf("%s\n", foo[i]); }
```

Or to use dynamic allocation:

```
char* foo[3]; int i=0;

for (i=0; i<3; i++) { char* temp = malloc(6); sprintf(temp, "VAL:%d", i); foo[i] = temp; }

for (i=0; i<3; i++) { printf("%s\n", foo[i]); free(foo[i]); }
```

Comment: "any sane compiler will place all those instances on top of each other" But you don't explain what he did *wrong*. You sound like it's a weird fluke of how compilers work. But the reason the compiler may (or may not) use the same location for it is that it is out of scope after the first iteration, so that variable doesn't "exist" anymore. So the OP's problem is that he's maintaining a pointer to something that is out of scope, which is undefined behavior

Comment: @newacct: You are right about the undefined behaviour. I purposely did not mention it, because I thought it more important to focus on how to get a working solution, rather than pointing out and explaining in detail all the errors in the non-working code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the second snippet is that all elements in `foo` point to the same variable, `temp`, which is out of scope when the second `for` is executed, which is undefined behaviour. Even if it was not out of scope all elements in `foo` would point to same buffer which is incorrect.

To correct, you need to make a copy of `temp` and store it in each element of `foo`. This could be achieved by using `strdup()` if available (if not `malloc()` and `strcpy()`):

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]); i++)
{
    char temp[6];
    snprintf(temp, sizeof(temp), "VAL:%d", i);
    foo[i] = strdup(temp); /* Must be free()d later. */
}
```

or changing the type of `foo` (as already suggested by [unwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28169/unwind)):

```
char foo[3][6];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]);i++)
{
    snprintf(foo[i], sizeof(foo[i]), "VAL:%d", i);
}
```

Other changes:

- Increased the size of `temp` to `6` as it requires the `5` characters `VAL:%d` *plus* the null terminator appended by `sprintf()`. The posted code has a buffer overrun because of this.
- Use of [`snprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to avoid buffer overrun.
- Use of `sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0])` to calculate number of elements in array `foo` instead of hard-coding the element count.

Answer (score 0):

The `temp` variable in the loop is probably re-using the same memory on each iteration, so you end up writing the same address into each `foo[]` slot. Then, even worse, that address becomes invalid to access when you exit the loop, causing undefined behavior.

You need to dynamically allocate each string, or use a string array with space for the actual string (`char foo[3][20];` or something).

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) You've declared `temp` as `char temp[5]` and you are stuffing it with more than 4 characters:

```
sprintf(temp,"VAL:%d",i);
```

there by causing sprintf to write beyond the end of the array as it has to write the terminating `\0`

2) The variable `temp` is local to the for loop and it goes out of scope once the loop ends.